# Custom control: Adding custom properties from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I'm a beginner in C# winforms.

I have a custom control of NumericUpDown that displays the selected measurement unit next to the value. Because the user can set different units I want that string to change with changing the property of the control. I have another Units class with enum Unit. I want Unit to be a property of the control.

```
public partial class NumericTextBox : NumericUpDown {

    protected override void UpdateEditText() {
        if (this.Value == this.Maximum) {
            this.Text = "Unlimited";
        } else {
            this.Text = this.Value + "Placeholder for units";
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe) {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}

class Units {
    public enum Unit { meters, feet, nauticalMiles }

    public Units() {
        dictionary.Add(Unit.feet, "ft");
        dictionary.Add(Unit.meters, "m");
        dictionary.Add(Unit.nauticalMiles, "nm");
    }
}
```

[image: The property that I would want to set]
[image: The numericupdown with units]

Comment: That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: *"Because the user can set different units I want that **string** to change with changing the property of the control."*  which **string** are you referring to?

Comment: @k1dev Placeholder.

Comment: You should be more specific in what you want to achieve. Could you post some pictures? I may have understood but I want to be sure.

Comment: @k1dev there you go, if that helps